# regular expression not able to use group to identify not matched string

Tags: c#

I have regular expression as:
`@"(?<Region>[\D]*)_(?<CollectionType>[a-z]_\d{2}_\d{2})_(?<Gender>M|F)_(?<AgeIdx>\d)_(?<Holder1>\d)_(?<FingerConditionIdx>[0-5])_(?<EorVNum>0|1)_(?<Holder2>\d_\d)_(?<UserID>[0-9]{7})_(?<FingerIdx>[0-9])_(?<ImgNum>[\d]*)_(?<EorVLetter>E|V).(?<extension>bmp)";`

I will read in the file name as:
`US_R_00_00_F_5_0_0_0_0_0_2231232_2_05_E.bmp`

Currently, I can use the foreach loop to print out the desire output.
However, for the file name, sometimes there are unexpected name like:

1. `US_C_00_00_F_5_0_0_0_0_0_2231232_2_05_Etest.bmp`
   Do I use IsMatch function for this example?
2. There might be out of order image number (caption group = ImgNum),
   I know I can use counter to compare with caption group, but once image number is out of order,
   rest of the number will not align properly, is there any way to improve the code ( if the current image number is not equal to counter, current image number will plus one and aligh with the counte)?
   Here is the code:

```
                int counter = 1
                
                foreach (string bmpEnroll in bmpEnrolls)
                {
                    //For store enroll bmp image number in the list, will compare later
                    //@"(?<Region>\w+)_(?<CollectionType>[a-z]_\d\d_\d\d)_(?<Gender>[a-z])_(?<AgeIdx>\d)_(?<Holder1>\d)_(?<FingerConditionIdx>\d)_(?<EorVNum>\d)_(?<Holder2>\d_\d)_(?<UserID>[0-9]{7})_(?<FingerIdx>\d)_(?<ImgNum>\d\d)_(?<EorVLetter>\w).(?<extension>\w+)";
                    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(Path.GetFileName(bmpEnroll), BmpFilesPattern(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    {
                        //Since we know the total of enrollment, we can just loop from 1 to total numbers of enroll
                        //For Non - Reconed BMP image
                        //Numbering: 01 - 50.
                        if (i.ToString().Length == 1)
                        {
                            //If it is 1, we need to add the 0 in front, and put into list
                            EnrollBmpNeededTotalList.Add(
                            match.Groups["Region"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["CollectionType"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["Gender"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["AgeIdx"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["Holder1"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["FingerConditionIdx"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["EorVNum"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["Holder2"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["UserID"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["FingerIdx"].Value + "_" +
                            "0" + i.ToString() + "_" +
                            match.Groups["EorVLetter"].Value + "." +
                            match.Groups["extension"].Value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //else, we just add them together, and put into list
                            EnrollBmpNeededTotalList.Add(
                            match.Groups["Region"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["CollectionType"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["Gender"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["AgeIdx"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["Holder1"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["FingerConditionIdx"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["EorVNum"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["Holder2"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["UserID"].Value + "_" +
                            match.Groups["FingerIdx"].Value + "_" +
                            i.ToString() + "_" +
                            match.Groups["EorVLetter"].Value + "." +
                            match.Groups["extension"].Value);
                        }
                        if (counter < Int32.parse(numsofEnroll.text()))
                            count += 1
                        esle
                            count = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Currently the way I am ding to create a hashset to store all the expected list and using except to filter the unwanted file name.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `String.Split`? (Once for the extension with `.` and then with `_` for the remaining parts?)